# MSI installation through Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, cmd, java-8, windows-installer

I need to install .msi file through my java code. Is it possible?
Or is it possible through spring boot?

I have .msi file in my local. I need to write a java code to run the .msi file either through windows script or directly?

Can I create and run windows.bat file dynamically in the program?

I tried like this :
Hi I am trying like this :

```
String[] command=
            {
                    "cmd"
            };
        String command1 = "msiexec /i “*Path of the installation.msi*\"";

        Process p;
        try {
            p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println(command1);
            stdin.close();
            p.waitFor();
        }
```

After runing i am getting below window dialog :
[image]

After clicking OK program is getting terminated.
Even if I give

```
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

then also same issue!

Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the path, command is correct. Gwe have to give path like this, considering escape sequences.

```
String command1 = "msiexec.exe /a \"C:\\Users\\{name}\\Downloads\\{.msi}\"";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```